# Process fresh salmon into Sushi / Sashimi salmon?

Tags: sushi, fresh, salmon, food-processing, sashimi

I am a Sushi and Sashimi lover, especially salmon flesh. I recently bought some fresh salmon from Taobao. It's not frozen and has been kept around 4°C for 24h (during delivery). The product page said it's suitable for eating directly. After eating a few slices I noticed something different from what I eat at a restaurant. I see some white fluidy solid in my sauce plate, which is possibly fat. I washed the flesh and applied juice from squeezed lemon to it before eating. I'd never met this phenomenon before.

- <s>What's that white fluid in fresh salmon flesh? (No quality issues)

  Is it fat? It does not dissolve in water or sauce.</s>
- How is this fresh salmon different from that in a restaurant?
- How should I process the salmon so that it gets consistent with the one in a restaurant? Or simplifying this question, how can I get rid of the "fat" (since there's no other issue)?

---

**Edit**: I can now confirm it's fat. It's exactly the white layer between red layers(fresh flesh). How do I stop it from "washing off"?

Comment: I don't know about the white stuff, but typically you freeze it for a couple of days to reduce the potential for parasites.  also see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/8603/67

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sushi fishes are usually flash frozen for a few days before being used for safety (to kill off bugs)
It might change the texture of the fish as it is unfrozen; the better the restaurant the better the fish will be unfrozen.

http://www.pbs.org/food/fresh-tastes/myth-sushi-grade/

> For fish that contain parasites, the FDA provides guidance under their
>   Parasite Destruction Guarantee. This states in part that fish intended
>   to be consumed raw must be “frozen and stored at a temperature of
>   -20°C (-4°F) or below for a minimum of 168 hours (7 days)”.

As for the fluid, I don't know, maybe fat or just water with dissolve fish protein (the thing that turns white when you cook salmon).

Comment: Exactly the thing that turns white when hot-cooked, but shouldn't that be attached to the flesh and not drop off while washing/seasoning?

Comment: Finally, you're right. It's the unfreezing process that matters.