# Fresh salmon that was frozen after: till when can it still be eaten raw

Tags: salmon, raw-meat, raw, frozen, sashimi

I always buy fresh salmon filet, cut it into pieces and put it in the freezer.
I usually take a frozen piece cut it and eat it raw.

**My question is:** for how long can a frozen salmon filet (frozen after being fresh) still be eaten raw without the need to cook it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21068/41), frozen food is safe indefinitely.

That being said, raw salmon that has simply been stored in your freezer for a while is **not** safe to consume without cooking. Not after 1 month, not after 1 week, not after 1 day. **Fresh salmon needs to be cooked**.

["Sashimi-grade fish" needs to be frozen at significantly lower temperatures](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/751/41) than most home freezers are normally set at, and lower than many are actually capable of. Unless you can guarantee that it has been consistently lower than -20° C for 7 days or -35° C for 15 hours, you shouldn't eat it raw. Either buy sashimi-grade salmon from a reputable source, or order it prepared at a reputable restaurant.