# How can I tell if the Salmon I buy is safe to eat raw?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, salmon, sashimi

If I buy a piece of cold Salmon in a supermarket, and it doesn't say anything about being ["Sashimi-grade"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/751/64104) or having been deep-frozen at X degrees for Y time - how can I know whether it's safe to eat raw?

Note: I live in the Netherlands, in case the answer varies by location.